# Flutter : Icon overflows a Row when the parent container is downsizing

Tags: flutter, dart, animation

I created a full custom side menu.
On mobile, I would like the menu to fully collapse.

So, I created the following structure :

```dart
AnimatedContainer
    Column
        Image          
        SizedBox,
        Padding
            MenuItem
```

where MenuItem widget is as bellow :

```
Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom:16),
      child: MouseRegion(
        cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            NavigatorKeys.navigatorKey.currentState?.pushNamed(route);
            // Callback call
            if(onClicked != null){
              onClicked!();
            }
          },
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Icon(
                icon,
                size: 48,
                color: theme.colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: AnimatedOpacity(
                  opacity: textOpacity,
                  duration: animDuration,
                  curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:16),
                    child: Text(
                      label,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      style: style,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

With this Layout, the text is collapsing perfectly.
But an overflow error is thrown because of the Icons.

GIF of the collapsing animation

[image]

To avoid the overflow, I tried to wrap the Icon Widget with Flexible.
But now we will have two Flex children for the Row, dividing by two the available space for each Widget.
We want the Icon to be width fixed and the text to take all the space remaining.

An idea to fix this behavior ?
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the Icon widget with Flexible?

Comment: @YashasMajmudar As said at the end of my post, yes I did. 
It is working, but it changes the behavior of the Row. The Text can only takes the half of the available space if we do so.

Comment: Have you tried using AnimatedBuilder instead of animated container and then passing animation value of width to the size constraint of the icon. This would reduce the icon size with the container. I can create an answer for this approach if you say.

Comment: @YashasMajmudar No, I didn't. I will have a look at the AnimationBuilder widget. 
But yes, if you have more detailed explainations, I would be greatful you could answer about this potential workaround. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `AnimatedBuilder` Widget. Official docs are here for reference: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedBuilder-class.html

You can use the below code as reference for your drawer and to get some idea about how to implement AnimatedBuilder.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Drawer extends StatefulWidget {
  const Drawer({super.key});

  @override
  State<Drawer> createState() => _DrawerState();
}

class _DrawerState extends State<Drawer> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final AnimationController animationController;
  Animation<double>? slideAnimation;
  late final Animation<double> iconSizeAnimation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
    );

    iconSizeAnimation =
        Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 48).animate(animationController);

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    // initialising here instead on init state as I need media query, you can add custom curves using curved animation
    slideAnimation ??= Tween<double>(
      begin: 0,
      end: screenSize.width / 2,
    ).animate(animationController);

    // Instead of using Animated container use Animated builder on a container which will execute using your animationController and pass the values you want to change as tween animations
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: animationController,
      builder: (context, child) {
        return SizedBox(
          // Animated width for slide
          width: slideAnimation!.value,
          height: screenSize.height,
          // Here you can specify how widgets in your row should be aligned
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Icon(
                // Your own icon
                Icons.add,
                // we use .value to get current animation value according to the animation controller
                size: iconSizeAnimation.value,
              ),
              const Expanded(
                child: Text('some text'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

You can modify your code taking this as reference.

Simply call `animationController.forward()` and `animationController.reverse()` to run the animation.

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Yashas and Jahan answers, I found a solution based on LayoutBuilder.

```
LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (context, constraints) {
        return Row(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                width: constraints.maxWidth>48?48:constraints.maxWidth,
                child: Icon(
                  icon,
                  size: 48,
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(...)
            ],
        );
     }
 )
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

Please check by wrapping the icons as below.

```
LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraint) {
    return Icon(Icons.access_alarms, size: constraint.biggest.height);
}),
```

Where constraint is 48 as you mentioned above.

Comment: It seems not be enough.